# Having Issues with getting 1 out of 2 legends splitting into two columns when they are both formatted the same? arcmap 10.4

Tags: gis, arcgis, legend-properties

Although I have been able to split one of the legends into two columns on my map the other one is proving problematic in doing so. I cannot see any differences in the properties of each legend in terms of the item column customizing.

Comment: This would be on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, convert the legend to graphics (by right clicking the image and selecting `convert to graphics`). Follow this up by ungrouping the image into different elements. You can then just move the items across into a second column manually.